# Expectation of R script does not match output

Tags: r

I am currently running this script, I do not understand the logic of this output. since I am new to R script I am unable to also understand why 0L is been used. Especially the Date column is doubled and i understand it but why is the original projection gives values from 1-10?

Output:

```
[[1]]
         Date
1  2020-01-01
2  2020-01-02
3  2020-01-03
4  2020-01-04
5  2020-01-05
6  2020-01-01
7  2020-01-02
8  2020-01-03
9  2020-01-04
10 2020-01-05
11 2020-01-06
12 2020-01-07
13 2020-01-08
14 2020-05-09
15 2020-01-10
16 2020-01-06
17 2020-01-07
18 2020-01-08
19 2020-05-09
20 2020-01-10

[[2]]
   Original Projection
1                    0
2                    1
3                    2
4                    3
5                    4
6                    5
7                    6
8                    7
9                    8
10                   9
11                  10
```

Script

```
clinAct <- data.frame(
  `Pr F Site Open` = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05")),
  `Pr L Subj` = as.Date(c("2020-01-06", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-08", "2020-05-09", "2020-01-10")),
  `Pr # required subj` = 1:5,
  check.names = F
)

original.projection <- function() {
  first_column <- data.frame(
    Date = c(clinAct$`Pr F Site Open`, clinAct$`Pr L Subj`),
    check.names = F
  )
  
  second_column <- data.frame(
    `Original Projection` = c(0L, clinAct$`Pr # required subj`),
    check.names = F
  )
  
  return(list(first_column, second_column))
}

original.projection()
```

Update:

```
original.projection <- function() {
  first_column <- data.frame(
    Date = c(clinAct$`Pr F Site Open`, clinAct$`Pr L Subj`),
    `Original Projection` = c(0L, clinAct$`Pr # required subj`),
    check.names = F
  )
  
  return(list(first_column))
}

original.projection()
```

The expected output for updated script:

```
Date         Original Projection
2020-01-01       0
2020-01-02       0
```

Comment: I do not get that output when I run it; I get the expected 0:5 (not 0:10). I would clear your environment, start a new session and rerun the code. And if that doesn't work, then maybe supply your R version because that's really weird.

Comment: Using `L` after a number, like `0L` means R should treat it as an integer rather than as a double-precision numeric variable - `str(0)` returns `num 0` and `str(0L)` returns `int 0`.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong so are you saying the concept above should retrieve me with a value of 0 wherever I have these concatenated dates?

Comment: @KSp this line `\`Original Projection\` = c(0L, clinAct$\`Pr # required subj\`)` says that the variable called `Original Projection` will be an integer zero followed by whatever values are in the `PR # required subj` variable from the `clinAct` data frame.

Comment: integer zero for the first row and then the values frrom the PR # required subj? okay thanks